# git merge: overwrite untracked files

Tags: git, merge, overwrite

I have a branch with some untracked files in it. I want to merge another branch onto it. 
The second branch contains a tracked file, which is untracked for the first branch. Following error occurs:

`error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:...`

Is there any possibility to overwrite these untracked files and replace them with the ones from the second branch without knowing which files they are?

I also tried `-X theirs`
seems not to work in this case.

Comment: There is nothing built in for this, but since Git is script-able, you can write your own: just read the set of untracked files (`git ls-files --others`) and the set of files in the commit you intend to merge (`git ls-tree -r <commit>`). The intersection of the two sets names the files that Git will need to overwrite. Move or delete those files and you are done with the preparation.

Answer (score 2):

Do a stash of your untracked files:

```
git stash -u
```

Then you can merge the branch.
From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash):

> If the `--include-untracked` option is used, all untracked files are
>   also stashed and then cleaned up with git clean, leaving the working
>   directory in a very clean state. If the --all option is used instead
>   then the ignored files are stashed and cleaned in addition to the
>   untracked files.

Comment: That's not an option. There are many unstaged files in the directory, that should not be deleted.

Comment: @ibot3 They won't be. You just need to merge that branch and pop the stash. The clashing files will raise  conflicts that you can then resolve.

Comment: I need an automatic way, without manually resolving conflicts

Comment: I’d suggest committing more often

Comment: Doing this has the potential to permanently delete some things from your gitignore list

Comment: @PatrickParker Not unless you use `--all` which I have never had to do, once.

Comment: Fair enough. I had so many untracked files (over 20 GB) I was scared what might happen if I tried this. So I did a force checkout of the branch I wanted to merge in, first. That allowed me to wipe out just the problematic untracked files.